# Spring - how to pass automatically http header between microservices

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-url, spring-resttemplate

I'm having multiple microservices

```
1. MangerApp 
2. ProcessApp
3. DoingStuffApp
4. .....
```

the "MangerApp Microservices" get an `Http-Request` 
I'm looking for a way to transfer automatically some of the `HTTP headers`
in the call, while I don't want to go over each place and do - add Headers, my `HTTP` headers are stored as a **thread-local Map**.

since I call to other `microservices`, with `RestTemplate` I have many different calls some `get/post/put/etc...`
changing each one them and passing the header manually is not that efficient.
I'm looking for a way to manage it, other than extending the `RestTemplate Class` now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` to achieve what you need.

1) Create a `HeaderInterceptor` implementing `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. In this example it gets the Authorization and Accept headers from a ThreadLocal and propagates them:

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor{

    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

                    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        List<String> authorization = HeaderThreadLocal.getAuthorization()
        List<String> accept = HeaderThreadLocal.getAuthorization();

        headers.addAll("Authorization", authorization);
        headers.addAll("Accept", accept);
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

2) Configure your `RestTemplate` bean adding the header interceptor:

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new HeaderInterceptor());
```

Comment: Read about here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor
which says it will intercept for every incoming call. "Our interceptor will be invoked for every incoming request", 

what I need is to intercept for every outgoing call

Comment: That’s what this implementation does. Baeldung’s article shows how to add a header to the response. My code adds it for the RestTemplate request, which is what you need.

Comment: I cant find the dependency for HeaderThreadLocal. Any help ? @codependent